# Regenerate Web API key of Google Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-security, firebase-console, google-cloud-console

How do I regenerate my Web API key for Google Firebase? I deleted the autogenerated one due to misguided reasons.

If it's not deletable, do I need to create just a new App or a new Project?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to your [API account](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?), select a project at the "Select a project" dropdown in the upper left, and "Create Credentials" of the API Key variety.

Firebase will link to your key automatically.

Comment: If there are multiple keys available in API account, do you know how Firebase "select" one of the keys? Each key may have different restrictions on who can use it & what APIs can be used.

Answer (score 2):

But after the key is reset it does not reflect with the new Web API key generated under firebase project settings.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new Web API Key, you should open the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select the project, then select Credentials from the left menu, and then hit "CREATE CREDENTIALS" and select "API key".

Because a Firebase project is a Google Cloud project, when you create a new Web API Key, the key is **automatically** added inside the Firebase project. It will take about 5 minutes to propagate. Also, don't forget to download the `google-services.json` and check if the new Web API Key is the same as the one in the Google Cloud Console. Unfortunately, such a change isn't reflected in the Firebase Console.