# Firebase: How can I generate a new Web API Key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

In the Firebase console, if you go to Settings > General, you can find your Web API Key.

Is it possible to get a new key, therefore invalidating the old one? If so, how do I do that? I'd prefer not to have to create a new DB and migrate all the data and settings.

---

[This SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838881/regenerate-web-api-key-of-google-firebase) doesn't work because my Firebase console's Web API Key doesn't match any of the ones found using those directions