# Accidentally deleted API key automatically created by Google Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I accidentally deleted api_key that automatically created by google firebase so I regenerated a new one and changed the api_key value in google-services.json file and restarted android studio, I tried to add some data to firestore and it worked well, but now 'Web API Key' in Project settings in `console.firebase.google` still holding the deleted api_key value and I can't change it..

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838881/regenerate-web-api-key-of-google-firebase) question similar to mine here but I need to know if
is this going to affect the work of the app later or it's not important to change the value in firebase project's settings?